# Lua callback "attemp to index global"

Tags: function, callback, lua, global, local

```
function AnotherSCT:OnNormalColorFontClick( wndHandler, wndControl, eMouseButton )
   local color = Color.new(0.5, 1, 0.5, 1)
   ColorGetter.GetColor(color, false, ColorCallBack, color)
end

function ColorCallBack(color)
  if color == nil then
    Print("nil")
      else
    wndMain:FindChild("NormalFontTypeTestText"):SetTextColor(color)
  end
end
```

The line:
wndMain:FindChild <--- generates "Attempt to index global 'wndMain'

How can i access wndMain in my callback function?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to `wndMain` in `OnNormalColorFontClick`? If so then you could either pass it to your callback as an argument, or define the callback locally within `OnNormalColorFontClick`, making it a closure that captures `wndMain`.

Edit: here is the "closure" solution.

```
function AnotherSCT:OnNormalColorFontClick( wndHandler, wndControl, eMouseButton )
    local color = Color.new(0.5, 1, 0.5, 1)

    local function ColorCallBack(color)
        if color == nil then
            print("nil")
        else
            wndMain:FindChild("NormalFontTypeTestText"):SetTextColor(color)
        end
    end

    ColorGetter.GetColor(color, false, ColorCallBack, color)
end
```

Comment: I cant make change to the ColorChanger or his functions. How can i define the callback locally?

Comment: Ok it works. Thanks for your help. I must call self.wndMain in the local callback function.

Comment: Maybe, I don't know that framework :) Glad it works.